# Android: Override viewmodel object in child fragment using Koin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, koin

I have the following case here, I got 2 fragments:

```
LoginFragment : BaseAuthFragment
RegFragment : BaseAuthFragment
```

and corresponding viewModels:

```
LoginViewModel : BaseAuthViewModel
RegViewModel : BaseAuthViewModel
```

LoginFragment has a LoginViewModel object
RegFragment has a RegViewModel object
BaseAuthFragment has a BaseAuthViewModel object

I am using Koin for dependency injection so that viewModel object declaration in BaseAuthFragment is smth like this:

```
private val viewModel: BaseAuthViewModel by viewModel()
```

BaseAuthViewModel keeps common livedata observable objects for both Login && Reg fragments, like loading, error, etc..

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to observe those common Livedata objects from BaseAuthViewModel inside of BaseAuthFragment, so that I don't have to copy the code in LoginFragment && RegFragment separately.

But inside of LoginFragment && RegFragment I should already have LoginViewModel and RegViewModel, which are children of BaseAuthViewModel, so is it possible to somehow override the viewModel object type in child fragments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define something like this:

Base class

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    /**
     * Every fragment has to have an instance of a view model that extends from the BaseViewModel
     */
    abstract val _viewModel: BaseViewModel

    ...
}
```

child class

```
class ChildFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override val _viewModel: ChildViewModel by inject()
...
}
```